# Route activity back to route dialog

Tags: botframework

I am looking for a way to optionally handle a follow up response to a message within a child dialog's MessageReceived method if it matches a limited number of strings, but if not then route the activity back to the route dialog if it doesn't match.

e.g. In the below scenario the message from the user should be handled within the current dialog.

User -> Bot  "Any events tomorrow?"

Bot -> User  "There are no events tomorrow"

User -> Bot  "What about Saturday?"

However, if the message isn't a follow up question like the below, then I want to essentially clear the stack and route the activity to the root dialog as if it is a new message because the user is asking something unrelated.

User -> Bot  "Any events tomorrow?"

Bot -> User  "There are no events tomorrow"

User -> Bot  "Book a meeting for me with Jon"

I am not sure how to send an activity back through the root from the MessageRecieved method of a child dialog so appreciate any pointers from anyone who has done this.

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK? Can you post your code?

Comment: Given that you wrote [This blog post](http://www.garypretty.co.uk/2017/04/13/using-scorables-for-global-message-handling-and-interrupt-dialogs-in-bot-framework/) I think I am missing part of your question.  It sounds like you want to use scorables to jump around between dialogs. Could you add some more info please to clarify?

Comment: Maybe you could use context.Done with a specific value and handle it in your root?